# Selnium/spotify API - Bulk like list of songs

Tags: csv, selenium-webdriver, automation, spotify

I have a csv list of 3000+ songs, name and artist, I want to "like" all the songs that appear on the list in my spotify account.

I looked for a solution inside spotify API but couldn't find a way to "like" a song.
I thought that I can do it in selenium, but I don't know if Spotify can detect it and block me.

Maybe you have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* save tracks via the API, through a PUT request via the Tracks endpoint: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/save-tracks-user